# passing dynamic options to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am programming a simple JS game. The game has some options, that can be set in administration and stored in MySQL database. However, I am not sure what is the best way to send these options to the javascripts.

Let's say that I have some game model object that has function that initializes the game.

```
var someGame = {
    init : function(options){
        this.difficulty = options.difficulty;
        this.numberOfMonsters = options.numberOfMonsters;
        // ....
    }
}
```

It has options parameter and these options come from database. How should I deliver these options into the game?

I have some ideas, but I would like to here your suggestions.

1. I can use AJAX to retrieve options, but I would pay for that by 1 extra request
2. I could just echo the options in PHP as javascript variables and call the function from HTML code, but based on what I read, JS should be separated.
3. I can create JSON object, but again, it would be mixing JS and HTML. Maybe if I would output the JSON into some invisible HTML element and then parse it by JS, it could work, but not sure if it's good way.
4. I can create some empty HTML element and store the options in its "data-" attributes.
5. I can dynamically create JS file using PHP, but is it worth of it? I just need to fill few dynamic variables
6. ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 is the most efficient.  It has no extra requests of the server and the data is already in the page when you need it.

You know your page needs these options for the server.  You might as well fetch them from the database and put them in your page's javascript when you build that page where they can be used immediately with no delay waiting for an ajax call.

There is no downside to putting them in the page.  I'm not sure what separation of JS you are trying to achieve.  Your options are JS code and they will be in a script in your page.  The separation I'm more familiar with is that you don't want javascript code mixed in with the HTML (e.g. inline event handlers).  This is not that.  You're putting script data in a script tag right along with your other scripts.  That is not a problem.

Here's commentary on each of your proposed ideas:

**1)  Use AJAX to retrieve options.**

As you say this is one extra request.  That extra request slows down the initialization time of your page and doubles the requests of your server to serve that page.  There simply isn't a need to retrieve this data via ajax unless you don't usually need this data or unless you need to pass some arguments to the request and those arguments can only be retrieved from the client side.

**2)  Echo the options in PHP as javascript variables**

Unless you don't usually need this data and it's expensive to retrieve on the server side or unless you need to pass some arguments to the request and those arguments can only be retrieved from the client side, it is most efficient to just put the data in the page when the page is rendered.  If you put them in as script variables, then you still have separation of HTML/JS.  You probably should make one object and put each data value as a property on that one object to lessen to top-level namespace pollution.

**3)  Create JSON object.**

There's no reason to use the text-based JSON format when you can just make them a direct javascript object as in the above option.

**4)  create some empty HTML element.**

There's no reason I'm aware of to put this data in your HTML rather than in your JS.  That would be mixing HTML/JS unnecessarily.

**5) Dynamically create JS file.**

No reason to create a separate JS file.  Just put this small amount of JS inline in script tags.

Comment: Thanks, so number 2 is winner. I thought that it's most suitable and fastest solution, I was just scared about this mixing JS/HTML stuff

Answer (score 1):

Options 1, 2 and 3 are usually quite alright for this kind of situations.

If you are generating the page from PHP and the variables/data is available then, I think it's perfectly fine to include something like this in your HTML:

```
<script>
yourScript.init(<?php echo json_encode($javascriptParameters); ?>);
</script>
```

Although you are quite right about separating JS code from HTML, putting JS into HTML for doing initialization tasks like this is quite common and a perfectly acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Option 6 - If you're not opposed to ditching the MySQL database, you could use something like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), where you can interact with it directly from JavaScript. This is nice because it eliminates the extra layer of the PHP backend where you're only using it to get access to data. Let me know if you're interested in this option or have any questions about it..

Comment: I have a CMS based on PHP, so it's not just extra layer between backend and data. But thanks, it looks interesting, I will try it someday